# multiple problems - old MTA exim4 - new MTA postfix - nessesary rewriting rules

Tags: configuration, postfix-mta, exim, rewriting

We run currently exim4 MTA in a closed Network. Its configured as satellite to a smart host. We're only sending in this configuration.
Because we use DavidFX the rewriting won't apply anymore, caused by the disposition-notification-to and return-reciept-to.

I get by with exim, but now we have to switch to postfix and I have trouble to understand how to transform my existing rewriting and add something to discard all the headers that just about any email software might be using.

I already googled for some Templates and documentation including manpages. I want to be informed before starting to configure. But it seems to be a special problem I have...

Following sample code of my rewriting rules in exim4.  I know it's a dirty way to ensure error delivery, but I didn't know an alternative.

```
begin rewrite
no-reply.location1@domain.local.de group.location1@example.com Fr
no-reply.location2@domain.local.de group.location2@example.com Fr
no-reply.location3@domain.local.de group.location3@example.com Fr
no-reply.location4@domain.local.de group.location4@example.com Fr
test.location@domain.local.de name.location@example.com FTrt
```

The no-reply addresses are only outgoing, there isn't possible to receive mails (security). The groups are in another area for office purposes. 
If I answer (in Outlook2010) the no-reply address, I would write to the no-reply instead of the group, caused by the additional headers from DavidFX, I think.
I see the rewriting work in generally because the correct envelope is within the headers.

The last address rewriting should ensure, that every mail from testing won't arrive its original destination but have to send to my personal address. While testing with DavidFX to echo@univie.ac.at I received the echo, not the origin mail, so the configured rewrite wouldn't apply completely.

Additional to the above problems, I have to ensure this with postfix config. 
May someone understand me, and some hints would appear. :)

Comment: Have you looked at aliases https://askubuntu.com/questions/244452/use-etc-aliases-for-outgoing-mail-relayed-by-postfix-with-local-domain

Comment: Thanks 4 comment, but it seems to be only a rewrite like mail an root --> deliver to xy@gmail.com 
So it may match the Tt-part in the last line, but not the other rewritings.

Comment: Okay my problem is now not anymore the rewriting. More the total different concept between exim and postfix. in exim I have already a complete suite for mailing. Postfix haven't already an accounting or authentification function. 
So please tell me, how to set up properly and which Packages are needed to run on rhel? By the way, apt-get won't work and I have to install everything over flash drive...